# Profvis and recursion

Tags: r, recursion, profiling

I have written a recursive algorithm which I want to profile, I set up a function `fun()` that will run the complete task. When I do

```
profvis::profvis(fun())
```

RStudio crashes. So, I ran

```
Rprof(tmp <- tempfile())
fun()
Rprof()
profvis::profvis(prof_input = tmp)
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

which isn't very useful. I can use `summaryRprof(tmp)` directly but I prefer profvis. Any tips for improving this output?

#### Notes

- I could remove `zeallot` but given the number of recursive steps it wouldn't matter, there are too many.
- I monitored memory use and CPU use, th e processes rsession and pandoc start to consume a lot of memory.
- I'm on R 3.4.2 and profvis 0.3.5.

Comment: Could you profile just one iteration? Do you think it would be informative in how this would translate down the "chain"?

Comment: Problem is that any iteration would recurse and I might need to look at the compete picture of the time spent. Ideally, the flame graph would just show time spent per line at the top level.

Comment: For now, kicking out zeallot worked for both performance and profiling, issue would probably still exist though for deeper recursions though.